# pivot_table values missing

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

[image]

I just simply reshape the `dataframe` as my wish. index is userid, and columns are subgameID, filled with rating as values. But all values become missing data.

Comment: You should provide a MCV example as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record - if you only check 2 columns like that, why don't you use pd.crosstab?

```
pd.crosstab(ratings_data.userID, ratings_data.subgameId, margins=True)
```

If you need pivot_table, then try to add argument `fillna = 0`.

You can also try to do it on small subsample of the data - maybe the NaNs are properly introduced (many userID belonged to only small subset of subgameID)?

Comment: If it solves your problem, could you mark it as correct answer?